# How to do date date comparison in Amazon Athena , Here my date columns are in string in the (yyyy-mm-dd) format

Tags: amazon-web-services, presto, amazon-athena

How  to do date comparison in amazon Athena ?- I am using the following query but ,it is not working - date(dt) between date('2020-01-01') and date('2020-01-31'). Please note here 'dt' is an string column.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Answer (score 2):

Query syntax for date is

```
date BETWEEN date '2014-07-05' AND date '2014-08-05'
```

[Source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/select.html)

Comment: This is the correct syntax for date literal, but OP's `date('2020-01-01')` is equivalent.